# Assignment statement value

Tags: python, variable-assignment

Everybody knows that in Python assignments do not return a value, presumably to avoid assignments on `if` statements when usually just a comparison is intended:

```
>>> if a = b:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if a = b:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>> if a == b:
...     pass
...
```

For the same reason, one could suspect that multiple assignments on the same statement were also syntax errors.

In fact, `a = (b = 2)` is not a valid expression:

```
>>> a = (b = 2)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a = (b = 2)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, my question is: why `a = b = 2` works in Python as it works in other languages where assignment statements have a value, like C?

```
>>> a = b = c = 2
>>> a, b, c
(2, 2, 2)
```

Is this behavior documented? I could not found anything about this in the assignment statement documentation: http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It's right there in the syntax:

```
assignment_stmt ::=  (target_list "=")+ (expression_list | yield_expression)
```

The tiny `+` at the end of `(target_list "=")+` means "one or more". So the line `a = b = c = 2` does not consist of 3 assignment statements, but of *a single assignment statement* with 3 target lists.

Each target list in turn consist only of a single target (an identifier in this case).

It's also in the text (emphasis mine):

> An assignment statement [...] assigns the single resulting object to **each of the target lists**, from left to right.

This can lead to interesting results:

```
>>> (a,b) = c = (1,2)
>>> (a, b, c)
(1, 2, (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fine example:

```
>>a,b,c  = b = 1,2,3
>>b
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = b = c = 2
b = 3
print a,b,c
>>> 2 3 2
```