# Magic assign for custom parameters

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to give user API for my library with easier way to distinguish different types of parameters which I pass to function. All groups of arguments are defined earlier (for now I have 3 groups), but attributes of them need to be constructed on run. I can do this in Django ORM style, where double underscore separates 2 parts of parameter. But it is very unreadable. Example:

```
def api_function(**kwargs):
    """ Separate passed arguments """

api_function(post__arg1='foo', api__arg1='bar', post_arg2='foo2')
```

Better way do this SQLAlchemy, but only to compare attributes and all args are defined earlier. Example:

```
class API(object):
    arg1 = Arg()
    arg2 = Arg()
class Post(object): #...
def api_function(*args):
    """ Separate passed arguments """

api_function(POST.arg1=='foo', API.arg1=='bar', POST.arg2=='foo2')
```

What I would like to achive is behaviour like this:

```
class API(object): # Magic
class POST(object): # Magic
def api_function(*args):
    """ Separate passed arguments """

api_function(POST.arg1='foo', API.arg1='bar', POST.arg2='foo2')
```

What have I tried:

- declare metamodel with defined `__setattr__`, but it rise on evaluation `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`
- declare `__set__`, but it is designed for known attributes

My questions are:

- Is it even possible in Python to work like in third snippet?
- If not, is there any really close solution to look like in third snippet? The best way should use assignment operator `API.arg1='foo'`, the worst `API(arg1='foo')`

Requirements -- should work at least at Python 2.7. Good to work on Python 3.2.

**EDIT1**
My first test, which is using equality operator (but it **NEVER** should be use in this way):

```
class APIMeta(type):
    def __getattr__(cls, item):
        return ApiData(item, None)

class API(object):
    __metaclass__ = APIMeta

    def __init__(self, key, value):
        self.key = key
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0}={1}".format(self.key, self.value)

    def __eq__(self, other):
        self.value = other
        return self

def print_api(*api_data):
    for a in api_data:
        print(str(a))

print_api(API.page=='3', API=='bar')
```

It is working right, but using `==` is suggesting that I want to compare something and I want to assign value.

Comment: what's wrong with `api_function(POST=dict(arg1='foo', arg2='foo2'), API=dict(arg1='bar'))`?

Comment: Because also I could use `api_function(POST(arg1='foo', arg2='foo2'), API(arg1='bar'))` which is more readable, shorter and more logical solution. But I'm trying to make this library most easy to read for people.

Comment: @zwierzak There is no way you can do it like in the third snippet. Variables can't have `.` in their name.  However, the other way is definitely doable depending on how you are expecting to access the arguments in `api_function`.

Comment: i disagree that it's more readable.  i wouldn't be sure what was going on if i read that, and i certainly wouldn't expect it to just be a lazy way to pass some named dicts.

Comment: @mr2ert: But this wouldn't be variable name, this assignment should return single object, which should be passed as `*args`. Moreover on left of of `.` is earlier defined class and on right is attribute of this class created on the run of application.

Comment: @Eevee: for me is, but this is not discussion what is or isn't more readable but is it possible to do such thing.

Comment: @zwierzak In python assignments with `=` can't return a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python don't allow to use assignment operator inside any other code, so:

```
(a=1)
func((a=1))
```

will rise `SyntaxError`. This means that it is not possible to use it in this way. Moreover:

```
func(API.arg1=3)
```

Will be treated that left side of assignment is argument `API.arg1` which is not valid name in Python for variables. Only solution is to make this in SQLAlchemy style:

```
func({
    API.arg1: 'foo',
    API.arg2: 'bar',
    DATA.arg1: 'foo1',
})
```

or

```
func(**{
    API.arg1: 'foo',
    API.arg2: 'bar',
    DATA.arg1: 'foo1',
})
```

or just only:

```
func( API(arg1='foo', arg2='bar'), POST(arg1='foo1'), POST(arg2='bar1'))
```

Thank you for your interest and answers.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** I don't know how much I like this schema you want.  But I know one annoying thing will be all the imports to call `api_function`. E.G. `from api import POST, API, api_function`

As I said in the comments, the first way is not possible. This is because assignment (`=`) is a statement not an expression, so it can't return a value. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7012742/assignment-statement-value)

But the other way you asked for certainly is:

```
class POST(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.args = kwargs
    # You'll also probably want to make this function a little safer.
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.args[name]

def api_function(*args):
    # Update this to how complicated the handling needs to be
    # but you get the general idea...
    post_data = None
    for a in args:
        if isinstance(a, POST):
            post_data = a.args
    if post_data is None:
        raise Exception('This function needs a POST object passed.')
    print post_data
```

Using it:

```
>>> api_function('foo')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 7, in api_function
Exception: This function needs a POST object passed.

>>> api_function(POST(arg1='foo'))
{'arg1': 'foo'}

>>> api_function(POST(arg1='foo',
...                   arg2='bar'
...                  )
...             )
{'arg1': 'foo', 'arg2': 'bar'}
```

Comment: It can be written even easier: `class POST(dict): pass`. I know about "problem" with imports, but it will be only a feature for API. Most of args would be passed as `**kwargs`, because other types of arguments would be used only occasionally.

Comment: You might want to use a `namedtuple` instead of a class for some constraints on names.

Comment: @WaleedKhan Good point. I decided to go with a class because I didn't know what the OP's constraints where, so I left it as open as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It's not the best in design, as the structure of the argument grouper is nested quite deep, so I'd appreciate feedback on it:

```
class ArgumentGrouper(object):
    """Transforms a function so that you can apply arguments in named groups.

    This system isn't tested as thoroughly as something with so many moving
    parts should be. Use at own risk.

    Usage:
    @ArgumentGrouper("foo", "bar")
    def method(regular_arg, foo__arg1, bar__arg2):
        print(regular_arg + foo__arg1 + bar__arg2)

    method.foo(", ").bar("world!")("Hello")()  # Prints "Hello, world!"
    """

    def __call__(self, func):
        """Decorate the function."""
        return self.Wrapper(func, self.argument_values)

    def __init__(self, *argument_groups):
        """Constructor.

        argument_groups -- The names of argument groups in the function.
        """
        self.argument_values = {i: {} for i in argument_groups}

    class Wrapper(object):
        """This is the result of decorating the function. You can call group
        names as function to supply their keyword arguments.
        """

        def __call__(self, *args):
            """Execute the decorated function by passing any given arguments
            and predefined group arguments.
            """
            kwargs = {}
            for group, values in self.argument_values.items():
                for name, value in values.items():
                    # Add a new argument in the form foo__arg1 to kwargs, as
                    # per the supplied arguments.
                    new_name = "{}__{}".format(
                        group,
                        name
                    )
                    kwargs[new_name] = value

            # Invoke the function with the determined arguments.
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)

        def __init__(self, func, argument_values):
            """Constructor.

            func -- The decorated function.
            argument_values -- A dict with the current values for group
                arguments. Must be a reference to the actual dict, since each
                WrappedMethod uses it.
            """
            self.func = func
            self.argument_values = argument_values

        def __getattr__(self, name):
            """When trying to call `func.foo(arg1="bar")`, provide `foo`. TODO:
            This would be better handled at initialization time.
            """
            if name in self.argument_values:
                return self.WrappedMethod(name, self, self.argument_values)
            else:
                return self.__dict__[name]

        class WrappedMethod(object):
            """For `func.foo(arg1="bar")`, this is `foo`. Pretends to be a
            function that takes the keyword arguments to be supplied to the
            decorated function.
            """
            def __call__(self, **kwargs):
                """`foo` has been called, record the arguments passed."""
                for k, v in kwargs.items():
                    self.argument_values[self.name][k] = v
                return self.wrapper

            def __init__(self, name, wrapper, argument_values):
                """Constructor.

                name -- The name of the argument group. (This is the string
                    "foo".)
                wrapper -- The decorator. We need this so that we can return it
                    to chain calls.
                argument_values -- A dict with the current values for group
                    arguments. Must be a reference to the actual dict, since
                    each WrappedMethod uses it.
                """
                self.name = name
                self.wrapper = wrapper
                self.argument_values = argument_values

# Usage:
@ArgumentGrouper("post", "api")
def api_function(regular_arg, post__arg1, post__arg2, api__arg3):
    print("Got regular args {}".format(regular_arg))
    print("Got API args {}, {}, {}".format(post__arg1, post__arg2, api__arg3))

api_function.post(
    arg1="foo", arg2="bar"
).api(
    arg3="baz"
)
api_function("foo")
```

Then, usage:

```
@ArgumentGrouper("post", "api")
def api_function(regular_arg, post__arg1, post__arg2, api__arg3):
    print("Got regular args {}".format(regular_arg))
    print("Got API args {}, {}, {}".format(post__arg1, post__arg2, api__arg3))

api_function.post(
    arg1="foo", arg2="bar"
).api(
    arg3="baz"
)
api_function("foo")
```

Output:

```
Got regular args foo
Got API args foo, bar, baz
```

It should be simple to scrape argument group names by introspection.

You'll notice the argument naming convention is hardcoded into the `WrappedMethod`, so you'll have to make sure you're okay with that.

You can also invoke it in one statement:

```
api_function.post(
    arg1="foo", arg2="bar"
).api(
    arg3="baz"
)("foo")
```

Or you could add a dedicated `run` method which would invoke it, which would just take the place of `Wrapper.__call__`.

Comment: Firstly, woah.  This is crazy, very impressive.  The only thing code wise I'd recommend is putting the `__init__`s first for readability reasons.  I don't really like how the function is called.  Maybe a little too alien from normal Python?

Comment: I would like to avoid such calling (it will be used for other purpose). But thanks for try.